# Partioning Guide for manually installing ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I am installing ubuntu 14.04 64Bit "Trusty Tahr" on my Dell inspiron laptop alongside my windows 8.

The laptop has an i7 processor with 8.0 GB of RAM (7.87 of which is usuable)

I have 100GB of unallocated free space on my hard drive set aside for my ubuntu installation and can add more if completely necessary or recomended.

I want to know what is the best way to divide this 100GB of hard drive between **root,** **home,** and **swap** partitions so that my operating system will work most efficiently.

Thanks,

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If you aren't doing memory-intensive work, you can get away with 4 GB or less of RAM. If you're completely unsure, stick to one partition for root and home.

Comment: I have home and root together. I gave it 61GB of swap, but I think that that is unnecessarily large (I do have a 1.8TB HDD).

Comment: I have a 1TBHDD so memory isn't really an issue as I have IMO tons of space for a personal latop.  I plan to use the distro primarily for general programming like c++, java, php, etc, ... as well as general web browsing

Comment: Just curious is there was a general rule of thumb in allocation for different partitions for ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

My standard partitioning would be:

- 512MB /boot ext2 - in case there is a problem with grub and loading kernel etc after a system crash, it's less possible for so small partition to be damaged then one huge root partition.
- 8GB Swap - OPTIONALLY(!) in most cases you don't need swap partition at all. If you don't have enough memory, add some, but 8GB looks reasonable.
- 12GB /  - per average Ubuntu 14.04 on my machines takes upto 4GB, so 12GB root partition should be enough
- /home  - when you keep your home directory separatelly it's much easier to change whole system without touching your home dir, or move your home to other computer

All of this assumes you will use your laptop for some simple home/office stuff and you need a lot of space for your home directory. But if you want to run some disk space consuming services like database server, you should make much smaller home partition and much bigger root (or separate /var) partition.

Comment: I will give that partitioning setup a try and will keep that in mind if I decide to setup a database server in the future.

Comment: Most desktops do not need the separate /boot. And most repair instructions for desktops on installing do not mention you have to also mount /boot if separate partition to reinstall grub. I would make / a bit larger, but do not know how large database may be.

Comment: When you see how many question you have here related to grub and crashed root partition - I will stick to my separate /boot.